# Clustering data by averaging where the gradient is small

Tags: python, numpy

My data that is fairly continuous but has different regions. I'm trying to detect the center of each such cluster (approximately).

Basically, the data is a list of 2D vectors, in a (N,2) numpy array. The data has a characteristic structure that looks like this:

[image: structure of data]

You can see the two clusters appear (partially) in the list and I would like to detect their centers (say, by averaging). I have computed the L2 norm of the gradient and it seems to correlate very well with the boundaries between clusters (of course).

Next, I'd like to average out all the data points that belong to each cluster, as defined by the magnitude of the gradient (unless someone has a better idea, of course). I'd like to avoid looping over the data and use vectorized operations instead so that it runs fast. This is the difficulty for me.

Thanks!

Constraints:

1. I can't use any library besides numpy and opencv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that uses a for loop, but it iterates over the clusters rather than over the values so you still have the benefits of vectorized operations.

I set up my test case in accordance to your problem description like so:

```
data = np.ndarray((30,2))
data[:10] = np.random.random((10,2)) * 4 + 60
data[10:20] = np.random.random((10,2)) * 4 + 70
data[20:30] = np.random.random((10,2)) * 4 + 80
norms = np.linalg.norm(np.gradient(data,axis=0), axis=1)
```

And I found the centers like this:

```
threshold = 5 # Specify how much greater the gradient is at the threshold

# get cluster boundaries by finding the indexes at which 
# the next gradient norm is significantly smaller
boundaries = np.where(norms[:-1] > norms[1:] + threshold)
# add start and end boundaries
boundaries = np.hstack((0,*boundaries,None))

centers = np.ndarray((boundaries.size-1,2)) # empty array for centers
# calulate the mean between each set of boundaries
for i in range(boundaries.size-1):
  centers[i] = np.mean(data[boundaries[i]:boundaries[i+1]],axis=0)

print(centers)
```

Which for my test case got me these centers:

```
[[62.34829355 62.46226224]
 [71.70243459 72.23661627]
 [81.54729804 82.25504445]]
```

Comment: Very nice! Seems efficient!

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use OpenCV, I think that the easiest way to get the job done would be using [`cv2.kmeans`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vectors = np.array([[64, 20],
                    [64, 21],
                    [65, 19],
                    [65, 20],
                    [66, 20],
                    [68, 19],
                    [74, 4],
                    [74, 7],
                    [74, 8],
                    [75, 3],
                    [75, 4]], dtype=np.float32)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 200, .1)
flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
_, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(data=vectors, 
                                K=2, 
                                bestLabels=None, 
                                criteria=criteria,
                                attempts=100,
                                flags=flags)

plt.scatter(vectors[:, 0], vectors[:, 1], s=30)
for x, y in centers:
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=300, marker='s')
```

[image: scatterplot]

Your data are represented as small dots while cluster centers are displayed as large squares.

Comment: K is what I'm trying to find though (along with the center for each cluster)

Comment: If the number of cluster is not known _a priori_ you should estimate it, for example, through the [elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering))